# React - get Item from local Storage

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and trying to set up a basic client-side session.  I am getting an error when I am trying to retrieve the username from the local storage. `SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0` Do you have some suggestions on to to fix it?

**NavBar.js**

```
const username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'));

const NavBar = props => {
  if (props.isAuth !== null) {
    return <div>
        ## here I am trying to display the username
        <p>Logged In as {{username}}</p>

    </div>;
  } else {
    return <span>Not logged in</span>;
  }
};
export default NavBar;
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Navbar isAuth={loggedIn} />
      </Router>
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            if (loggedIn) {
              localStorage.removeItem("token", null);
              setLoggedIn(null);
            } else {
              localStorage.setItem("token", true);
              localStorage.setItem("username", "pierre-alex");
              setLoggedIn(true);
            }
          }}
          value="toggle"
        >
          Toggle
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `username` is an object then we need to stringify it while storing it in localStorage. We can then parse it to get the data.

```
localStorage.setItem('username',JSON.stringify({name:'Jonh Doe'}));
const username = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username');
```

If the value stored in localStorage is not an object then we don't need to parse it. We can access it like below.

```
const username = localStorage.getItem('username')
```